# Interpreting Coefficients of brms Bernoulli family model

Tags: r, brms

I am struggling with interpreting model results from a brm() model. The first result uses scaled and centered data with command scale(df$column, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE).

```
> summary(global.use.initial)
 Family: bernoulli 
  Links: mu = logit 
Formula: use ~ 1 + iogs_std + ipred_std + idepth_std + idry_std + iopenwater_std + ibroodaltered_std + icc_std + ivosum_std + ic + entrancedir + boxage_std + pguardtype + neighbor_std + wetland.type + bpp + (1 | year) + (1 | site) 
   Data: Masterintialusewatt.initalonly.naomit (Number of observations: 825) 
  Draws: 4 chains, each with iter = 16000; warmup = 8000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup draws = 32000

Group-Level Effects: 
~site (Number of levels: 3) 
              Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sd(Intercept)     1.04      1.06     0.03     3.90 1.00     9107    10772

~year (Number of levels: 4) 
              Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sd(Intercept)     0.61      0.47     0.15     1.87 1.00     9120    13385

Population-Level Effects: 
                                            Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept                                      -0.25      0.99    -2.47     1.79 1.00          11429     8999
iogs_std                                        0.65      0.18     0.31     1.01 1.00    26064    24495
ipred_std                                      -0.31      0.20    -0.70     0.09 1.00    21572    23319
idepth_std                                      0.55      0.15     0.27     0.84 1.00    32939    23456
idry_std                                        0.20      0.11    -0.02     0.42 1.00    34767    23558
iopenwater_std                                 -0.18      0.10    -0.40     0.00 1.00    35240    22896
ibroodaltered_std                               0.12      0.12    -0.11     0.34 1.00    34813    20159
icc_std                                        -0.42      0.17    -0.75    -0.10 1.00    34900    23951
ivosum_std                                     -0.22      1.13    -2.49     1.98 1.00    41638    20542
icInland                                        0.66      1.71    -3.07     4.56 1.00     9981     7007
entrancedirN                                    0.22      0.22    -0.22     0.67 1.00    29635    24328
entrancedirS                                    0.53      0.24     0.05     1.00 1.00    29805    25259
entrancedirW                                    0.42      0.23    -0.03     0.87 1.00    30410    23288
boxage_std                                     -0.20      0.08    -0.36    -0.04 1.00    40105    23315
pguardtypePVC                                  -0.32      0.28    -0.87     0.23 1.00    26824    26541
neighbor_std                                    0.11      0.21    -0.31     0.53 1.00    33995    21789
wetland.typeFreshwaterEmergentWetland           0.50      0.88    -1.10     2.35 1.00    24640    21095
wetland.typeFreshwaterForestedDShrubWetland     0.40      0.47    -0.51     1.34 1.00    22295    22118
wetland.typeFreshwaterPond                      0.82      0.51    -0.15     1.85 1.00    23207    22517
bppSingle                                       0.69      0.23     0.24     1.15 1.00    35732    22478

Draws were sampled using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
```

However, calculating the mean and standard deviation as follows:

```
mean(Masterintialusewatt.initalonly.naomit$iogs) #167.6615
sd(Masterintialusewatt.initalonly.naomit$iogs) #36.39035
```

Would yield an estimate for iogs to be 191.31, which seems much too high. I also tried to fit the same model with original data that is not scaled and centered:

```
> summary(global.use.initial.notrans)
 Family: bernoulli 
  Links: mu = logit 
Formula: use ~ 1 + iogs + ipred + idepth + idry + iopenwater + ibroodaltered + icc + ivosum + ic + entrancedir + boxage + pguardtype + neighbor + wetland.type + bpp + (1 | year) + (1 | site) 
   Data: Masterintialusewatt.initalonly.naomit (Number of observations: 825) 
  Draws: 4 chains, each with iter = 16000; warmup = 8000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup draws = 32000

Group-Level Effects: 
~site (Number of levels: 3) 
              Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sd(Intercept)     1.05      1.09     0.03     4.09 1.00     3653     1636

~year (Number of levels: 4) 
              Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sd(Intercept)     0.60      0.46     0.14     1.84 1.00     6740     4123

Population-Level Effects: 
                                            Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept                                      -2.62      1.23    -5.17    -0.17 1.00     5495     3844
iogs                                            0.02      0.00     0.01     0.02 1.00    18645     9082
ipred                                          -0.01      0.00    -0.02     0.00 1.00    19890    22756
idepth                                          0.03      0.01     0.01     0.04 1.00    17927     8886
idry                                            0.01      0.01    -0.00     0.02 1.00    34444    23004
iopenwater                                     -0.01      0.00    -0.01     0.00 1.00    28589    23942
ibroodaltered                                   0.00      0.00    -0.00     0.00 1.00    43801    22835
icc                                            -0.01      0.00    -0.02    -0.00 1.00    36510    24297
ivosum                                         -0.05      0.23    -0.49     0.40 1.00    25013    10504
icInland                                        0.58      1.66    -3.21     4.04 1.00     4462     2158
entrancedirN                                    0.23      0.23    -0.22     0.66 1.00    26924    24410
entrancedirS                                    0.53      0.24     0.06     1.00 1.00    18732    20977
entrancedirW                                    0.42      0.23    -0.02     0.87 1.00    26950    23822
boxage                                         -0.02      0.01    -0.03    -0.00 1.00    30976    24597
pguardtypePVC                                  -0.32      0.28    -0.87     0.24 1.00    23372    24004
neighbor                                        0.00      0.00    -0.00     0.00 1.00    36968    22291
wetland.typeFreshwaterEmergentWetland           0.51      0.87    -1.09     2.31 1.00    28404    22713
wetland.typeFreshwaterForestedDShrubWetland     0.41      0.47    -0.50     1.36 1.00    21968    22256
wetland.typeFreshwaterPond                      0.83      0.51    -0.13     1.85 1.00    18487    22855
bppSingle                                       0.69      0.23     0.25     1.13 1.00    25042    24148

Draws were sampled using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
```

Now the estimates for continuous variables are all very small with error estimates of 0 or near 0. Neither these very small values or error estimates of 0 make any sense. I know the Bernoulli family uses a logit link, but how can I transform something with an estimate of 0 and 95% confidence intervals of 0 to 0 as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the estimates are too bad? If you have a continuous predictor with a large range, the unstandardized coefficients (log-odds here) can be very small, indeed.

I think results are easier to interpret as odds ratios (you could `model_parameters(global.use.initial.notrans, exponentiate = TRUE)` from the [*parameters* package](https://easystats.github.io/parameters) to obtain odds ratios), or even more easier on the response scale, i.e. calculate predictions. You could do this using the [*ggeffects* package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects), `ggpredict(global.use.initial.notrans, "iogs")` to get predicted probabilities for you focal terms of your model.